# AWS AppSync Query to shape response data (Similar to Group By in SQL)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I have one DynamoDB table with all the data I need for the client, however, I want to shape the data the client receives to reduce client-side manipulation.

My Schema:

```
type StateCounty {
    id: ID!
    StateName: String
    CountyName: String
    FIPSST: Int
    FIPSCNTY: Int   
    Penetration: String
    Date: String

}
```

and to return a custom query I have the type:

```
type Query {
  getStateCountybyState(StateName: String): StateCountyConnection
}
```

This works - and with a simple query

```
query  getStateCountybyState {
     getStateCountybyState (StateName: "Delaware")   {
      items { 
       StateName
       CountyName
       Date    

    }
   }
  }
```

the results are returned as expected:

```
 {
      "StateName": "Delaware",
      "CountyName": "Kent",
      "Date": "02-01-2017"
    },
    {
      "StateName": "Delaware",
      "CountyName": "Sussex",
      "Date": "02-01-2016"
    },
    {
      "StateName": "Delaware",
      "CountyName": "New Castle",
      "Date": "02-01-2018"
  }
```

etc.

I would like to return the data in the following format:

```
 {
   "StateName": "Delaware" {

     { "CountyName": "Kent",
      "Date": "02-01-2017"
      },
     {
      "CountyName": "Sussex",
      "Date": "02-01-2016"
     },
     {
      "CountyName": "New Castle",
      "Date": "02-01-2018"
     }
 }
}
```

I have tried adding  GroupCounty: [StateCountyGroup] to the schema:

```
type StateCounty {
    id: ID!
    StateName: String
    CountyName: String
    FIPSST: Int
    FIPSCNTY: Int   
    Penetration: String
    Date: String
    GroupCounty: [StateCountyGroup]
}
```

and then a reference to that in the query

```
query  getStateCountybyState {
     getStateCountybyState (StateName: "Delaware")   {
      items { 
       StateName
       CountyName
       Date  
       GroupCounty: [StateCountyGroup] 
    }
   }
  }
```

I think my issue is within the resolver  - currently, it is configured to use the StateName as a key, but I am not sure how to pass the StateName from the primary query to the subquery.

Resolver:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "query" : {
        "expression" : "StateName = :StateName",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":StateName" : { "S" : "${context.arguments.StateName}" },
        }
    },
    "index" : "StateName-index-copy",
    "select" : "ALL_ATTRIBUTES",

}
```

Any guidance appreciated - I have gone through the documentation several times, but cannot find an example.

***UPDATE***

I tried the suggestion below from Richard - and it is definitely on the right track, however, despite multiple variations on the theme, I either return null or the following error (I eliminated some of the county objects returned in the error for brevity):

```
"message": "Unable to convert set($myresponse = {\n  \"Delaware\": 
[{SSA=8000, Eligibles=32295, FIPS=10001, StateName=Delaware, SSACNTY=0, 
Date=02-01-2016, CountyName=Kent, Enrolled=3066, Penetration=0.0949, 
FIPSCNTY=1, FIPSST=10, SSAST=8, id=6865}, 
{SSA=8010, Eligibles=91332, FIPS=10003, StateName=Delaware, SSACNTY=10, Date=02-01-2016, CountyName=New Castle, Enrolled=10322, Penetration=0.113, FIPSCNTY=3, FIPSST=10, SSAST=8, id=6866}, 
{SSA=0, Eligibles=10, FIPS=10, StateName=Delaware, SSACNTY=0, Date=02-01-2018, CountyName=Pending County Designation, Enrolled=0, Penetration=0, FIPSCNTY=0, FIPSST=10, SSAST=0, id=325}, 
{SSA=8000, Eligibles=33371, FIPS=10001, StateName=Delaware, SSACNTY=0, Date=02-01-2017, CountyName=Kent, Enrolled=3603, Penetration=0.108, FIPSCNTY=1, FIPSST=10, SSAST=8, id=3598}, 
{SSA=8020, Eligibles=58897, FIPS=10005, StateName=Delaware, SSACNTY=20, Date=02-01-2016, CountyName=Sussex, Enrolled=3760, Penetration=0.0638, FIPSCNTY=5, FIPSST=10, SSAST=8, id=6867})    \nnull\n\n to class java.lang.Object."
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the above, it sounds like your original query is returning the correct results that you want but not in the response format that you would prefer, as you would like the "StateName" to be a top-level JSON key with the value being a JSON object of the state which you passed in as an argument. Is that accurate? If so then why not use the same query that already works but with a different response template. Something like:

```
#set($myresponse = {
  "$ctx.args.StateName": $ctx.result.items
})    
$util.toJson($myresponse)
```

Note that `$myresponse` isn't exactly the same as you had above as your example with `"stateName" : "Delaware" { ... }` wasn't completely valid JSON so I didn't want to make an assumption on what a good structure would be, but the point remains if you're already getting the proper results from your query I would just try to change the structure of your GraphQL results.

Now if I misread the above and you're NOT getting the proper results from the query, the other way that I could read your statement of "primary query to the subquery" is that you're trying to apply an additional `"filter"` to your query results. If that is the case then you need something like this:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "query" : {
        "expression" : "StateName = :StateName",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":StateName" : { "S" : "${context.arguments.StateName}" },
        }
    },
    "index" : "StateName-index-copy",
    "select" : "ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
    "filter" : {
      "expression" : "#population >= :population",
      "expressionNames" : {
        "#population" : "population"
      },
      "expressionValues" : {
        ":population" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.population)
      }
    }
}
```

I used an example here where maybe your query also needed to filter by the population size in each county. This may not be representative of what you're looking for but hopefully it helps.

**EDITED WITH MORE INFORMATION 4/16/18**

I've written up more information on this in a step-by-step manner, to go through the concepts in pieces.

The key here is not just the response template, but also the fields that you're requesting to be returned (as this is the nature of GraphQL). Let's walk through this by way of example. Now that you're returning an individual item with GraphQL (since your response template is converting an array to a single item) so you'll need to change the expected GraphQL query response type. Suppose you have a GraphQL type in your schema like this:

```
type State {
    id: ID!
    population: String!
    governor: String!
}

type Query {
    allStates: [State]
}
```

If you just convert the response in the template as above you'll see an error like "type mismatch error, expected type LIST" if you run something like this:

```
query {
  allStates{
    id
    population
  }
}
```

That's because your response is no longer returning the individual items. Instead you'll need to change the GraphQL response type `[State]` to match what your template conversion is doing `State` like so:

```
type State {
    StateName: String
}

type Query {
    allStates: State
}
```

Now if your resolver **request** template is doing something that returns a list of items (like a DynamoDB scan or Query) you can convert the list to a single item in the **response** template like so:

```
#set($convert = {"StateName" : $ctx.result.items })
$util.toJson($convert)
```

Then run the following GraphQL query:

```
query {
  allStates{
    StateName
  }
}
```

And you'll get a single object containing an array of your results back:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allStates": {
      "StateName": "[{id=1, population=10000, governor=John Smith}]"
    }
  }
}
```

However while this might be pointing out the errors you are having, this is returning a `StateName` and from your original question I think you are looking to do a bit more by combining records in the response for some optimization, along with some potential filtering. One way to do this would be to create an array (or you could create a map {}) and populate it based on some conditional. For example modify your query to have a `StateName` as an argument:

```
type Query {
    allStates(StateName: String!): Post
}
```

Then you can filter on this in the resolver response template, by using a `#foreach` and an `#if()` conditional, then calling `.add()` only if items in the response are for the state which you requested:

```
#set($convert = {"StateName" : [] })
#foreach($item in $ctx.result.items)
  #if($item["StateName"]=="$ctx.args.StateName")
    $util.qr($convert.get("StateName").add("$item"))
  #end
#end
$util.toJson($convert)
```

So now you could run something like this:

```
query {
  allStates(StateName:"Texas"){
    StateName
  }
}
```

And this will give you back just the results for that specific state which you passed as an argument. But you'll notice the selection set of the query is `StateName`. You could introduce a bit more flexibility by having the possible states listed in your GraphQL type:

```
type State {
    StateName: String
    Seattle: String
    Texas: String
}
```

Now you alter your resolver response template to use the argument for building up the return array since it can specify this in the selection set:

```
#set($convert = {"$ctx.args.StateName" : [] })
#foreach($item in $ctx.result.items)
  #if($item["StateName"]=="$ctx.args.StateName")
    $util.qr($convert.get("$ctx.args.StateName").add("$item"))
  #end
#end
$util.toJson($convert)
```

So I can run this query:

```
query {
  allPosts(StateName:"Seattle"){
    Seattle
  }
}
```

And I get back my result. Note though that passing `Seattle` as the argument but requesting back `Texas`:

```
query {
  allPosts(StateName:"Seattle"){
    Texas
  }
}
```

This will not work as the response object you created in your map was `Seattle: [...]` but you had `Texas` as the selection set.

The final thing that you might want to do is have multiple states returned, which you could do by building up one giant map keyed by the state name, or maybe it's done using the arguments or the selection set through adding state names to the return type as demonstrated above. That's up to you so I'm not sure how you'll want that but hopefully this demonstrates how you can manipulate the responses to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much @Richard for pointing me in the right direction, makes sense to shape the data in the _Response_ mapping, I am trying a few options, will post the final version that works for me later today.

Comment: I am definitely struggliing with the Velocity Templating Language  - Have been unable to resolve - I get an error message, which shows the array of objects for the correct StateName  - I have tried multiple variations to see if it is a parsing issue. Error added to the original post.

Comment: @AshleyW I made some edits to the response, hopefully it helps some. I think the error you added to the end is related to using a map vs an array, which you'll need to build up a little differently. I'd also suggest going through this programming guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-programming-guide.html

Comment: - thank you so, so much for taking the time to provide such a detailed response! Really appreciate it.